# Managing service accessibility in MacOS Sierra - what is the changed schema definition?

Tags: bash, sqlite, macos-sierra

In Mac OS X 10.9-10.11 there were 6 columns in Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db SQLLite3 database, but now there are 7 (bash script errors out now trying to run an INSERT statement) in 10.12 aka MacOS Sierra. Where can I find the schema definition for the new updated database, to add a new service accessibility entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCC.db is now protected by [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) on macOS Sierra.

You can read it, but you cannot write/modify it (even if your process / script is running with root privileges). Editing the TCC.db directly has never been supported, and because of some recent [high-profile apps doing this](http://applehelpwriter.com/2016/08/29/discovering-how-dropbox-hacks-your-mac/), Apple has locked it down.

Users can still alter Accessibility settings via:

**System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

Comment: For scripting purposes, what would be the replacement methodology for adding VPN connections? What do IT folks need to write this in?